# Python: How to write a sequence of code?

Tags: python, lambda, block

I am currently teaching myself python 3 and there's one thing that bugs me: I mean there's everything I expect, including lambda. But, how do I wrote a code block?

For example how do I write the following simple program code in python (2 or 3):

```
(  (lambda () (display "hello ") (display "world") (newline))  )
=> hello world
```

Now python:

```
=> >>> lambda :print("hello") print("world");
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you mean this,

```
>>> f = lambda : print("hello","world")
>>> f
<function <lambda> at 0x7faeca581d08>
>>> f()
hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you write Python. Lambdas are syntactic sugar for *very simple* functions only, and can only contain a single expression. If you want to do anything else, you have to write a function.

```
def hello_world():
    print("hello")
    print("world")
```

Note that the fact that this is not a lambda makes no difference whatsoever; you can still pass `hello_world` around as a first-class object.

Comment: Good explanation, but your code is printing two lines, when it should be one: `print('hello world')`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to sequence multiple expressions inside a lambda, it's possible to sort of "fake it" by constructing a data structure out of multiple subexpressions. Python will evaluate the items in the data structure as it builds the data structure. A tuple is one of the more efficient data structures to use:

```
>>> f = lambda: (print('Hello ', end=''), print('World'))
>>> x = f()
Hello World
```

Note that **f** returns a tuple that contains the return values of the two **print** function calls, each of which is **None**.

```
>>> x
(None, None)
```

This works the way you expect it to work because Python is guaranteed to evaluate the expressions in the tuple *in order* from left to right, as described here:

- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists

Comment: I agree that my example is not canonical Python, but it does answer the question: it demonstrates how to evaluate more than one statement in a single lambda.